# Ionic Framework - Redirecting using $state.go

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

Many people seems to be facing this same issue all over the internet when dealing with Ionic Framework core service i.e. $state. I literally spent 3 hours today and can't figure it out.

I have the following file structure:
Controllers:

1. UserAccessController
2. OrdersController
3. etc.

and I have a single service file (will split services later) that contains service called by UserAccessController. I am trying to redirect the user after signup to activation page. To do that I use:

```
$state.go('activate');
```

In another project, that worked fine but in this project am getting an error saying:

> Cannot read property 'go' of undefined
>       at UserAccessController.js:17

I declared the $state in the controller file but still not working and couple of lines before line 17 (highlighted by debugger) state.go did work. Please assist. Code is below to help

UserAccessController:

```
angular.module('starter.controllers').controller('UserAccessController', ['$scope', '$http', '$state', '$q', 'CreateUserService', function($scope, $http, $state, $q, CreateUserService){
    //$scope.$state = $state
    /*Function to redirect user to signup view*/
    $scope.loadSignupView = function(path){
       $state.go(path);                                                                   
    };

    $scope.signup = function(user) {

        if(user !== null)
        {
            var returnValue = CreateUserService.createAccount(user); 

            returnValue.then(function(data) {

                console.log("Value is 1");
                $state.go('activate'); //line 17
            }, function(error) {
                console.log("Error Caused");

            });            
        }else{
            console.log("Something went wrong while adding user");   
        }

    };

}]);
```

The app.js file has the following declaration and routes:

```
var app = angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.controllers', 'starter.services']);
```

and the routes are:

```
.state('login', {
    url: '/login',
    templateUrl: 'templates/user-access/login.html',
    controller: 'UserAccessController'  
  })

  .state('activate', {
    url: '/activate',
    templateUrl: 'templates/user-access/activation.html',
    controller: 'UserAccessController'
  })
```

Can anyone advise on what is wrong here. Thanks,

Comment: Could you provide a fiddle?

Comment: @iWörk too many files involved and its really messy.Anything specific I can post here?

Comment: Some working code which reproduces your error would be useful.

Comment: @iWörk then it is exactly the UserAccessController code....it works as in handling relation with service and showing the console messages afterwards. only the redirection fails with the error specified above.

Comment: @iWörk I literally didn't do anything and it just worked now....that's really strange.